# Query Syntax not working for multiple objects in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have created my model objects (DTO's) from EF's code first approach from an existing database and table selection. I am able to join multiple tables using method syntax but query syntax's fails to initialize object on the second `dbcontext` while joining.

I tried to replicate if method syntax works and it does work but query syntax doesn't except the first statement and fetching from single table.

Method syntax

```
var customers = procontext.Customer
                          .Join(procontext.ROLODEX, cust => cust.rolodex_sak, 
                                                    rol => rol.rolodex_sak, 
                                                    (cust, rol) => new { customerid = cust.customer.code, fname = rol.lname)});
```

Query Syntax

```
var customers = from cust in procontext.Customer
                join rol in procontext.rolodex on cust.rolodex_sak = rol.
```

When doing rol and ., it doesn't show any property and when I reverse the line rol fetches all the properties but then cust fails to load customer objects. So only first statement works in query syntax.

Answer (score 0):

My bad I was using "=" instead of equals, it works now.